why is my texture bake leaving dark spots
im not sure why after baking a high poly texture to my low poly it is leaving dark spots

Could be a number of things. Can you share your .blend file? You can upload it using the editor (by [edit]ing your question).

Im not sure if this is the answer to every problem but instead of doing the texture bake with tangent i did it with object space.
so for the space type you can do object space or tangent i switched it to object space. then in the node editor i switched the normal map type to object space as well and this resulted in my model not having dark spots.

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.
